# Why can't I edit a post made on Meta?

Tags: support

Whenever I try to edit a post on the Meta, it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suggested edits are not allowed for questions and answers on meta. This means that you need to surpass the reputation threshold to enable the respective privileges for edits.

These are:

- 100 reputation - edit community wiki posts
- 2000 reputation - edit normal posts

Answer (score 6):

Suggested edits are not enabled on Meta.

Comment: except for tag wikis, if I'm not mistaken.